# Spark Zeppelin slow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I run spark, zeppelin cassandra on a server with 2x20 core, 64 GB RAM but very slow for complete job (6-9 second for 1 million rows). Pls give me some suggestion
[image]

[image]

Comment: try do to ***.explain*** on dataframe after groupBy to see execution plan... check whether filters are pushed down in execution plan... try to tune ***spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows*** and ***spark.cassandra.input.split.size***

Comment: what is your table schema? and also add output of `df_kv_cassandra.explain`